# Find if the sentence has 3 consecutive words

Tags: javascript

You are given a string with words and numbers separated by whitespaces (one space). The words contains only letters. You should check if the string contains three words in succession. For example, the string "start 5 one two three 7 end" contains three words in succession.

Input : String
Output : Boolean

This is what I'm trying to do, please point out my mistake. Thanks.

```
function threeWords(text){
    let lst = text.split(' ');
    for (let i=0; i< 3; i++) { 
        if (typeof lst[i] === 'string' &&  Number(lst[i]) === NaN) {return true}
        else {return false;}}
}
```

Comment: You're returning true after finding one word.

Comment: Also you are only going through 3 words, you need to go though all the words in the sentence.

Comment: @croraf thanks I see it. Is the logic I'm using correct for the if statement?

Comment: "string contains three words in succession" Create a variable that tracks the number of consecutive words.

Comment: `typeof lst[i]` is always going to be `string`, so no need to test for that. And there are edge cases using `Number(string)`, e.g. `Number('Infinity')` will not evaluate to `NaN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd rather continue with your code than use regex, here are your issues:

1. You only loop over 3 of the elements in lst. Loop over the entire length of the list.
2. You try to check if Number('somestring') === NaN. In JavaScript, NaN === NaN is False. Use [isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) instead.
3. Once you find a list element that is not a number, you return True. You should have a variable that keeps track of how many words there are in succession (resetting to 0 when you find a number), and return True when this variable is equal to 3.

Here is the fixed code:

```js
function threeWords(text) {
   let lst = text.split(' ');
   let num_words = 0;

   for (let i = 0; i < lst.length; i++) {
      if (isNaN(Number(lst[i])))
         num_words++
      else
         num_words = 0
      
      if (num_words === 3)
         return true 
   }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: `isNaN(Number('Infinity'))` -> false

Comment: Instead of isNaN(Number(lst[i])) you can use isNaN(lst[i]) && isNaN(parseFloat(lst[i])) which would take care of some of the edge-cases regarding isNaN

Answer (score 0):

Might be easier with a regular expression:

```js
const result = /([A-Za-z]+( |$)){3}/.test('start 5 one two three 7 end');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: what is (  |$) doing?

Comment: It matches either a space or the end of the string